# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @OID AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(105, 106)',
        @startDate DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2017, 11, 01, 17, 0, 0, 0),
        @endDate DATETIME =  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2017, 11, 25, 17, 0, 0, 0)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Point) 
                      FROM Value
                      GROUP BY Point
                      ORDER BY Point
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT timestamp,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select timestamp, point, valuenumeric
            from value where point in ' + @OID + ' and Timestamp between ' + 
@startDate + ' and ' + @endDate + '
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            avg(valuenumeric)
            for point in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
```

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the `datetime` to `varchar` before concatenating with `string`

Also you need to append two more single quotes around the datetime parameter to enclose the date with single quotes.

To avoid all these hassle, I would suggest to use parameterised sql.

```
set @query = 'SELECT timestamp,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select timestamp, point, valuenumeric
            from value where point in ' + @OID + ' and Timestamp between  
@startDate and @endDate 
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            avg(valuenumeric)
            for point in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query,N'@startDate datetime, @endDate Datetime',@startDate,@endDate;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working now. Only thing is 'Timestamps' are not in order.

Comment: @ Pரதீப்  Thank you so much. Where exactly do I need to 'Add Order by Timestamp' ?

Comment: @Learner `..) p Order by timestamp'`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not in these lines, the issue in the dynamic sql part where you are appending the `datetime` data types `@startdate` and `@enddate` to strings. It should be:

```
....
Timestamp between ''' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @startDate, 121)+ ''' and ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@endDate, 121) + '''
        ) x
...
```

You need also to add more `'` so that the query is composed correctly as a dynamic sql query.

---

So your full query will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@OID as NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(105, 106)',
@startDate datetime = convert(datetime,'01-11-2017 6:10:00 PM',105),
 @endDate datetime =  convert(datetime,'30-11-2017 6:10:00 PM',105);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Point) 
                from Value
                group by Point
                order by Point
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'');

set @query = 'SELECT timestamp,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select timestamp, point, valuenumeric
            from value where point in ' + @OID + ' and Timestamp between ''' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @startDate, 121)+ ''' and ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@endDate, 121) + '''
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            avg(valuenumeric)
            for point in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p ';


 execute(@query);
```

- [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d00dce/17).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working now. Only thing is 'Timestamps' are not in order.